# Ant Script for converting multiple file formats using mappers- creating double extension files

Tags: ant, type-conversion, global, file-type, mappers

I want to convert multiple file formats to a single file format.
Example: D:\myrepo\rough  has 3 files
1. abc.sql
2. def.xml
3. ghi.dmp

I want them all to be converted to .txt using glob mappers.

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<project name = "roughone" default="taget1">
    <target name= "target1">
      <move todir="D:\myrepo\rough">
      <fileset dir="D:\myrepo\rough">
      </fileset>
      <mapper type ="glob" from="*" to="*.txt"/>
      </move>
    </target>
</project>
```

This is giving 
1. abc.sql.txt
2. def.xml.txt
3. ghi.dmp.txt where as i need only abc.txt,def.txt and ghi.txt.

Plz let me know how this can be fixed(from= "*.*" is not helping too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `globmapper` with the following [`<regexpmapper>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#regexp-mapper):

```
<regexpmapper from="^(.*)[.][^.]+$$" to="\1.txt"/>
```

The above regular expression captures the part of each file name before the final period. The regular expression also discards whatever extension the file previously had.

The double "$$" is needed because Ant would interpret a single "$" as the beginning of a property reference.